# 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'guild'

Tags: python, discord.py

i want the bot to give the user a specific role when he click on the message reaction, but i have a problem with `guild` method, when i click the message reaction that what printing in the terminal:

*role = discord.utils.get(reaction.guild.roles, name="skribbl")
AttributeError: 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'guild'*

and this is my code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self,reaction):
        role = discord.utils.get(reaction.guild.roles, name="skribbl")
        if reaction.message_id == 694520377300484137:
            if reaction.emoji == "❤️":
                reaction.author.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `reaction` object does not directly link to the guild. You will need to use `reaction.message.channel.guild` instead of `reaction.guild`.

Also is there a particular reason you are using `on_raw_reaction_add` instead of just `on_reaction_add`? 99% of the time `on_reaction_add` will be more efficient as it also uses the cache: [reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)